# .zshrc function for homebrew

Tags: zsh, homebrew, zshrc

I use the homebrew package manager and the z-shell. I'm trying to implement a function to create a list of available packages that would be accessible to the grep function. Here's what I've got so far:

```
function bsearch() {
 brew search | less >| ~/.brewsearch; grep $1 ~/.brewsearch
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that I'm not sure of what to put in place of $1. I'd like to be able to run the command as follows:

```
bsearch foo
```

but what ends up happening is that the function ends up looking for a file because of the argument $1.

In short, the question seems to be: how do I allow for a string in this function? (I'm new to all this).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why not just use `brew search`, Homebrew's built-in search tool?

Comment: The command doesn't output a list in alphabetical order but rather has some sort of pseudo-organization to it that makes it difficult to browse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to write a function. Just run `brew search foo`.

The command also accepts a regular expression between slashes, e.g. `brew search /foo/`

Check Homebrew's man page (`man brew`) for more details.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I'm looking for a solution to this for two reasons: 1. I'd like to know how to implement a string as in the above problem and 2. `brew search` or `brew search foo` prints a list that is in some sort of pseudo-order that makes things difficult to browse.

Comment: When I run `brew search whatever`, I get a list of results sorted alphabetically and divided into columns. If what you want is a single column, you can just run `brew search foo | less` or `brew search foo | cat`.